# How to retrieve database sql data and store to hash in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in database:

| id  |  param1  |  param2 | param3 | param4 | param5 |

| 1  |  value11 |  value12 | value13 | 18 | value15 |

| 2  |  value21 |  value22 | value23 | 17 | value25 |

| 3  |  value31 |  value32 | value33 | 10 | value35 |

Now I wan to retreive data from database, param2 and param4, and sort the data by param4

```
@data={

'0'=>{
     'param2'='value32',
     'param4'='value34'
   }

'1'=>{
     'param2'='value22',
     'param4'='value24'
   }

'2'=>{
     'param2'='value12',
     'param4'='value14'
   }

}
```

what I plan to do is Sort database and store sorted result in a variable

loop through this sorted result and retrieve data,save as hash in array.

but im not sure how I can do this(dun know ruby syntax well)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question has invalid code, and does not exactly match your described intention. I am assuming you are after something like this:

```
@data=[
  { param2: 'value32',
    param4:'value34' },
  { param2:'value22',
    param4:'value24' },
  { param2: 'value12',
    param4: 'value14'}
]
```

Which can be obtained by something like this:

```
@user.employees.pluck(:id, :name).inject([]){ |result, element|
  result.insert(-1, {param2:  element[0], param4: element[1}) 
}
```

If not, you should be able to tweak this to your needs. Get to know inject, it's awesome. My favorite description of it is the [excellent tutorial by Jay Fields](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html).